# Get destination view controller when pressing back on navigation bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

When we perform a segue, it is easy to get the destination view controller so we can pass data to it using the prepare(for:) method.

I'd like to know the correct way to do this when the back button of a navigation controller is pressed.

I've managed to piece together something that works, but it feels wrong to be using my knowledge of the hierarchy of the view controllers within the navigation controller rather than getting the destination dynamically.  Maybe i'm overthinking it?

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParent: parent)

    // This method is called more than once - parent is only nil when back button is pressed
    if (parent == nil) {
        
        guard let destination = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? MyTableViewController else {
            return
        }
        
        print("destination is \(destination)")

        // set delegate of my networking class to destination here
        // call async method on networking class to retrieve updated data for my table view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, trying to do that makes for too tight of a coupling. The VC you are navigating *away from* shouldn't need to know about where it's headed.

Probably better to implement your `networking class` methods in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` inside your `MyTableViewController` class.

However, you could give this a try:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    
    // make sure we're in a navigation controller
    guard let navC = navigationController else { return }
    
    if navC.viewControllers.firstIndex(of: self) != nil {
        // we're still in the nav stack, so we've either
        //  pushed to another VC, or presented a full-screen VC
        //  (or maybe something else)
        return
    }
    
    // we've been removed from the nav stack
    //  so user tapped Back button
    print("back button tapped")
    
    // see if we're navigating back to an instance of MyTableViewController
    guard let destVC = navC.viewControllers.last as? MyTableViewController else {
        return
    }
    
    // do something with destVC...
    print("on our way to", destVC)
}
```

Note: I just did this as an example... it would need plenty of testing and possibly additional case handling.